# Clarification on Fiddler's Transfer Timeline View

Tags: asp.net, performance, fiddler

I am trying to measure performance of the server side code.  Looking at the request from the client, Fiddler gives me the following view:

[image]

Fiddler's [documentation](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/timeline.asp) states: `The vertical line indicates the time to first byte of the server's response (Timers.ServerBeginResponse)`.

Does that mean the time of servers TCP response (e.g. ACK) or does it mean to tell me that the server has compiled all the data in less than half a second and took about 5 seconds to transfer it?

Comment: sounds like the latter is true!

Answer (score 2):

[TTFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte) is the time from the moment the request is fired to getting the first byte back from the server as a response. It includes all the steps for that to happen.

> It is the duration from the virtual user making an HTTP request to the
>   first byte of the page being received by the browser. This time is
>   made up of the socket connection time, the time taken to send the HTTP
>   request and the time to taken to get the first byte of the page.

So yes less than 1/2 second to respond, then 5secs to transfer.

Comment: That does not jive with my results.  I know the server side takes at least 5 seconds to get the results from the database.  This is a WCF call - does that matter?

Comment: Interesting, it's possible it's streaming data from your database via ASP.NET into the response, but it depends on your implementation. How are you measuring 5 secs?

Comment: No, it's a return for a WCF function call, which by definition does does not stream.  Besides, I see in the profiler that the database call is taking 5 secs.  The code is basically this: call sproc, convert DataTable to List<Foo> and return it to the client.

Comment: Oh it's probably because .Net sends the headers prior to the content. This will make the first byte occur much earlier than the main body.